# $3d$ coordinate transformation with given the directions of the new coordinate

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given the original $3d$ coordinate $XYZ$. Now I got three vectors $ix, iy, iz$ in $XYZ$ each has the same direction of $x,y,z$ axis respectively of the new coordinate after transformation and the $t=(1,2,3)$, then how could I work out the final transformation matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is linear transformation between two basis. Let $(x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2), (x_3,y_3,z_3)$ be the coordinate of the new axis. The transformation matrix is
$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1&x_2&x_3\\y_1&y_2&y_3\\z_1&z_2&z_3\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$

Edit:

Let's assume this matrix is $M$. Our goal is 
$$M\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\y_1\\z_1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},M\begin{pmatrix}x_2\\y_2\\z_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},M\begin{pmatrix}x_3\\y_3\\z_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

because $\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\y_1\\z_1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}x_2\\y_2\\z_2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}x_3\\y_3\\z_3\end{pmatrix}$ are the new coordinate units. This gives
$$M\begin{pmatrix}x_1&x_2&x_3\\y_1&y_2&y_3\\z_1&z_2&z_3\end{pmatrix}=I_3$$
where $I_3$ is the $3D$ identity matrix. The result then follows.

Comment: Sorry not quite understand the linear transformation with geometric point of view. Are (x1,y1,z1), (x2,y2,z2), (x3,y3,z3) the unit vectors with same directions of xyz axis of the new coordinate system?

Comment: @JewelSue: Yes. They are the unit vectors of the new xyz axis in terms of the original axis XYZ.

Comment: Cheers. Does this transformation hold whatever the two coordinates are left or right hand? In my case it is a left-to-left one.

Comment: @JewelSue: It does not matter whether it is left or right handed. But I made a mistake. I edited it.

Comment: Actually I found another document which says your original answer is correct..... I'm sorry but do you have any document that explains this in detail?

Comment: @JewelSue: I found some article with my original matrix yesterday but cannot find it any more. However, after some thinking, I believe that is from a different point of view. I will edit to show how I get the inverse.

Comment: sorry still not quite get it. In my opinion, since M is the transformation matrix, the unit vector (1,0,0) of original coordinate that owns the same direction with x- axis, should be transformed to (x1, y1, z1), namely (1,0,0)M=(x1,y1,z1). Anything I got wrong here?

Comment: @JewelSue: Then maybe I didn't get what you meant. Is $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ the coordinate of the new $x$-axis in terms of the original one, or is it the original $X$-axis in terms of the new coordinates? That totally determines whether you use inverse or not.

Comment: Initially (x1,y1,z1) is only a vector in original coordinate and it is the coordinate of the new x-axis in terms of the original coordinate and  so do (x2,y2,z2) and (x3,y3,z3). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @JewelSue: Then it should be inverse. The vector $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ is in the original coordinates. In the new coordinates, since it is the new $x$ axis, it becomes $(1,0,0)$. Our transformation sends the original coordinates of a vector to the new coordinates of a vector. So $M\cdot original = new$.

Comment: Got it. I was confused by thinking the (1,0,0) of original coordinate should be transformed to (x1,y1,z1) of the new one but actually it doesn't. Thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: @JewelSue: You are welcome. By the way, you can accept my answer by clicking the check mark beside it.

Comment: Sorry just last one comment. Since any two of (x1, y1, z1), (x2, y2,z2), (x3,y3,z3) are orthogonal and each of them is unit vector, so the M actually equals to [1st row: x1,y1,z1],[2nd row: x2, y2, z2], [3rd row x3, y3, z3] isn't it?

Comment: @JewelSue: That is correct if they are orthogonal and unit vectors.